# In Windows 10 (22H2), network drives are not reconnecting after re-connecting to the VPN. Error: The local device name is already in use

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, vpn, connection

A user is connecting to a work network using a FortiClient VPN client.  When the VPN connection drops, the user re-connects to the VPN, but they are unable to re-connect to the network drives.  If they restart their computer and connect to the VPN, then the network drives connect.

[image]

I checked the GPO and it's set to re-connect.

[image]

Comment: Does the network drive show with a red X on it in Windows Explorer? If so, does double-clicking on it reconnect?

Comment: Note, "Reconnect" as shown in your image does not mean "reconnect in case of failure", it means reconnect on subsequent reboots. it is the same as the /PERSISTENT flag on the `net use` command. https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html
Since the network drive was not torn down properly, if you touch the drive, it will attempt to reach the share again, but will be unable to, without first cleaning it up. what kind of file server does the share point to? windows or samba?

Comment: I have noticed on my NAS that enabling "durable handles" has reduced issues with network drives and smb share mounts when there are interruptions like the NAS reboots or whatever.  this may help provide more info: https://serverfault.com/questions/759359/difference-between-durable-file-handles-resilient-file-handles-and-persistent-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to switch the user over to a batch script for mapping the drives instead of using a GPO.

In Group Policy Management, I stopped the GPO from being applied to the user by:

1. Clicking on the GPO
2. Selecting the Delegate Control tab
3. Clicking on the Advanced button, then clicking the Add button
4. I Searched for the user, then I clicked OK.
5. Under Permissions, I checked the box next to Apply Group Policy, and
   I choose Deny
6. Lastly, I clicked the OK button

On the user's computer, I ran gpupdate /force

Then, I restarted the user's computer

This is the template for the batch file.

```
net use r: /d
net use r: \\servername\share1

net use s: /d
net use s: \\servername\share2
```

Answer (score 0):

> If they restart their computer and connect to the VPN, then the
> network drives connect.

That is fairly normal for corporate VPN connections. In particular, if network mappings had already been made, the error you see just reconnecting the VPN with the same mapping will occur as you see.

What you might do is check your network connection to see why the connection is dropping in the first instance.

You could perhaps make a script to disconnect remote mappings.  Put such shortcut on the desktop. Run it before reconnecting the VPN.

```
NET USE Z: /Delete
```

If you are using a GPO for drive mapping, a batch script is usually more reliable and flexible for remote users.

Another approach (one I use) is to remove the network mapping from the VPN connection.  Put the shortcut for mapping connection on the desktop.

Then you connect the VPN, run the script to connect network drives.

If the VPN disconnects, you now have a script to disconnect drives before trying to reconnect VPN.

```
NET USE Z: \\Server\Drive   /user:username
```

This is overall easier in the long run because you can work around errors.

It is also useful to use Windows User Scripts (GPedit) to disconnect remote drives on shutdown / logoff.  Then each restart or startup is a fresh time for connections.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing reply, John!  The user is connected via WiFi at home.  I don't know if it's a 2.4 GHz or a 5G connection.

Comment: Ask the user to check their network card drivers and make sure the WiFi router is up to date.

Comment: I made a note in my answer that Batch Scripts for remote users are often as good or better than GPO.  GPO is great in the office on the local LAN.    @Kent Allard

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how the users reconnect their network mappings,
so I'll assume that they run a batch script like:

```
net use r: \\servername\share1
net use s: \\servername\share2
```

If that's the case, then the problem is clear : The VPN has
disconnected, but Windows doesn't know that. For Windows, the mappings
are still there, so when the batch file is run after the
reconnection to the VPN, the user gets the
error of "The local device name is already in use".

The solution is to make the batch file safer, by deleting the
share before re-creating it. The batch will then look like:

```
net use r: /d
net use r: \\servername\share1
net use s: /d
net use s: \\servername\share2
```

Comment: They don't run any batch scripts.  Everything is mapped via the GPOs.  Thanks for the script.

Comment: So how do users reconnect? Or they just expect it to be done automatically?